# "Swivel" connection vs Male NPT on dual check valve: understanding the connection size and type designations

Tags: plumbing, terminology

Do I understand correctly that this [LF7-10-U3 1 1/4X1](https://www.watts.com/products/plumbing-flow-control-solutions/backflow-preventers/dual-checksdual-checks-with-atmospheric-vent/lf7/lf7-10-u3-1-14x1) dual check valve would be threaded, just like a garden hose, directly onto the meter's outlet-side male threads, and then on the downstream side of the valve there needs to be a male-threaded copper connector on the domestic piping, and the union fitting of the check valve would be threaded onto it?

Also, I am not sure about the (nominal?) sizing. Are the threads of domestic water meters all a single standard size in the USA? Our Neptune water meter says "5/8 T-10".  Would the 1 1/4 swivel fitting be compatible or too big for the Neptune's threads?  And on the downstream size of the valve, does 1" refer to the nominal diameter of the copper *pipe* that it is designed to fit, or to the actual I.D. of its female *thread*, or its nominal pipe size?

Comment: Most pipe sizing is close to the inside diameter of the pipe, with sight differences with different pipe material.  Then you have different thread types, a few can match but most do not.  Unless you really know your plumbing, I usually find it better to take as much as possible a long with good measurements/descriptions/pictures of what you can't take, to a store for fitting of the pieces

Comment: I really don't get this compatibility complexity.  The meter has 5/8 threads. There's a $300+ device that allows you to retrofit a backflow preventer. https://www.usabluebook.com/meter-resetter-w-3-inlet-backflow-preventer-5-3-8-24656     Do I need some sort of adapter between the 5/8 thread and 3/4 NPT?  Something like this: https://www.pollardwater.com/product/ay-mcdonald-58-x-34-in-swivel-nut-x-mpt-brass-reducing-meter-coupling-m74620ef/_/R-3765014?gclid=Cj0KCQiAtOmsBhCnARIsAGPa5yZJZzW6nHDSLksthwoZkrUPujIqt782WV1Fpp7F5SDVUv8BUTSNu9QaArQyEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: 5/8(outside measured diameter) threads on a meter seem small.  That size might go with a 1/2 inch pipe or tubing.  There are many different sizes(pipe) of back flow preventers and many different types and sizes of adapters.  The fewer joints to do what you want should be a target, each joint is a possible leak.

Comment: The meter manufacturer offers three sizes, 5/8 being their smallest, and that's what the utility company just installed. They didn't give me any choice in the matter. If I understand the reducing coupling naming correctly, "5/8 x 3/4 in. Swivel Nut x MPT Brass Reducing Meter Coupling" would mean "5/8 Swivel Nut  x 3/4 MPT", so that I'd end up with 3/4 MPT threads on the house-piping side of the meter.